# How to specify python package in cmake?

Tags: python, cmake

I am using the below CMAKE command. It shows an error. Is this the correct way to specify. The document specifies that it can be placed but doesnt provide an example.

`find_package(Python3 3.6.12 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)`

Comment: "It shows an error." is not a problem description with which we can help you. Please, add **exact error message** into the question post.

Answer (score 0):

```
include_directories(C:/Programs/Anaconda3/envs/pyth36/include)
link_directories(C:/Programs/Anaconda3/envs/pyth36/libs)
find_package(PythonInterp 3.6 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)
find_package(PythonLibs 3.6 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS Development)
```

This answer works for me.